# Sorting list of tuples of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

```
[((D,A),0.0),((D,C),0.0),((D,E),0.5)]
```

I need to sort the list as:

```
[((D,E),0.5),((D,A),0.0),((D,C),0.0)]
```

I have used the `sorted()` function and I am able to sort based on values `0.5, 0.0`... But I am not able to sort on the alphabetical order as I need the list to be sorted in descending order by the numbers and in ascending order of alphabets if the numbers have same value.

Comment: `sorted(li, key=lambda t: (-t[-1],t[0]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a tuple as the sort key with a negative on the float to reverse the order:

```
>>> li=[(('D','A'),0.0),(('D','C'),0.0),(('D','E'),0.5)]
>>> sorted(li, key=lambda t: (-t[-1],t[0]))
[(('D', 'E'), 0.5), (('D', 'A'), 0.0), (('D', 'C'), 0.0)]
```

If you cannot do negation (say on a string or letter value or something non numeric) then you can take advantage of the fact that the Python sort function is stable and do the sort in two steps:

```
>>> li=[(('D','A'),'A'),(('D','C'),'A'),(('D','E'),'C')]
>>> sorted(sorted(li), key=lambda t: t[-1], reverse=True)
[(('D', 'E'), 'C'), (('D', 'A'), 'A'), (('D', 'C'), 'A')]
```

Comment: There is a great [overview](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) on how to sort in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly, you could supply `sorted` with an iterable that is the result of another `sort`:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> t = [(('D','A'),0.0),(('D','C'),0.0),(('D','E'),0.5)]
>>> sorted(sorted(t), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
[(('D', 'E'), 0.5), (('D', 'A'), 0.0), (('D', 'C'), 0.0)]
```